# How to programmatically store a long string in Mac keychain?

Tags: xcode, string, cocoa, keychain

I want to store a long string in an encrypted, secure location and figured the keychain was a great place to do it.  I found [Adam Gerson's example](http://agerson.net/example-some-common-uses-keychain) on common keychain uses, which I understand and implemented, but the string I want to store is too long and truncates.  (I just used a placeholder username).

The string I'm trying to store is 1300+ characters long, and the password only seems to be storing 1023 characters.  I don't want to break up the string, so is there a way for me to store this string in a keychain?  And if so, can you point me toward any working examples?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [RHKeychain](http://rheard.com/blog/2012/05/rhkeychain/) for a working implementation that is able to store data of any arbitrary length.

It provides a simple and easy to use wrapper to the Mac OS X keychain to create, edit and delete generic password items.

Available on [GitHub](http://bit.ly/NXTId7). BSD Licensed.

Updated: Added unit tests for 2000+ chars